# react native application metro errors

Tags: react-native, babeljs, metro-bundler

I am building a react native application and I started getting some random metro errors with seemingly no source.

[image]

There also seems to be lots of warnings spammed into the metro console:

```
transform[stderr]: The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
transform[stderr]:      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
transform[stderr]: to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
```

I have tried a number of things such as:

- deleting node_modules folder and re-downloading
- cleaning android build
- Adding the plugins to babel config as mentioned in the above console log

My current package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.8.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.0.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "axios": "0.26.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-input-prompt": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My babel config:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', '@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share component which gives this error?

Comment: There is nothing to indicate any component throwing this error. Currently it errors after it finishes loading the application through metro.